# AysncTask for Downloading Web Content in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask

I am trying to get the html code of a web page using AsyncTask<> in Android, the code works and I am able to retrieve the content, but I have to wait for a long time for the app to load, until then only a while screen is being shown. This is the code for AsyncTask<> :

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

int info;
String result;
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
        HttpsURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        while(info != -1) {
            char i = (char) info;
            result += i;
            info = inputStreamReader.read();
        }
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Fail";
    }
}
}
```

This is the code in MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String result;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
        result = downloadTask.execute("https://www.listchallenges.com/fifty-favorite-fried-foods").get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i("Done", result);
}
}
```

How can i get the app to load immediately after it is opened and log the value of result?

Comment: Maybe try delaying your background task using Handler().postDelayed{}, giving 500 ms delay.

Comment: I tried delaying the background task, the screen is no longer blank, but the code in the background task does not run for 30 seconds, how do i get the code to run immediately after the app opens up?

Comment: How do you know it's not running? Maybe it's running but because of the network, it's taking the time. Try some debugging, put logs at the start of your task, and at the end, check if it explains anything.